# Adding text around a circle with pages

Tags: software-recommendation, pages

How do I add text around a circle I'm using for a logo?  I have a circle filled in with some initials on the inside.  I want to add the company name around the outside of the circle.

Comment: Not sure we're looking at pages online or pages for iOS or pages for Mac, but this might need other software so I added software recommendation tag in case people can suggest something other than pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature Pages '09 or Pages '13 provides (unlike Microsoft Word with the Wordart).

As XAleXOwnZX suggested you definitely should look at softwares that are made for what you want like InkScape or Illustrator.

Answer (score -1):

You can try [Art Text](https://text.design/art-text/), the app offers different shape presets for text, including ring and freehand splines. The resulting work can be exported as an image file and used in Pages, Keynote or anywhere else.
[image]

Comment: I'm not voting -1 since the question is pretty vague about the requirements. Ideally, the text would be editable, but if Pages simply doesn't allow plug in then to solve this you'll need more advanced layout like Illustrator or a program to rasterize the image and embed that. Thanks for the suggestion - I'm sure some people will love this solution.

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! Please note that you must [explicitly state](/help/promotion) that you are affiliated with this product.